# Database design: One table or splitting into 2 different childtables

Tags: database-design

I need to store some data that has a 1:1 relationship with the parent table. Data is very much like with different car types (coupe, hatchback, crossover, etc.) with the only difference that it consists of just two different entities (type1 and type2) with identical set of attributes holding varying values. Each record in the referring parent table may pertain to one of either two of these types or both at once. I'm not quite sure what would be the best way to tackle this from a design perspective. What would you say, should I go for the single table design like

```sql
CREATE TABLE childTab (
    id ...,
    type ...,
    attr1 ...,
    attr2 ...,
    attr3 ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, type),
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES parentTab (id)
)
```

or I'm better off doing

```sql
CREATE TABLE childTab1 (
    id ...,
    attr1 ...,
    attr2 ...,
    attr3 ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES parentTab (id)
)

CREATE TABLE childTab2 (
    id ...,
    attr1 ...,
    attr2 ...,
    attr3 ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES parentTab (id)
)
```

Comment: What if there will be a 3rd type in the future? Create another table? NO! You design should not be depended on changes like that.

Comment: The point is, there are definitely only two types